# SSMA cannot read meta data (missing runtime components)

Tags: sql-server, migration, ms-access, sql-server-2017, ms-access-365

What I want to do should be rather easy: Use SSMA to transfer internal Access tables and queries to SQL-Server.

On my Notebook I'm running SQL-Server 2017 and Office 365 (32 bit)

As I have 32 bit Office (company's choice ...), I installed the *"SSMAforAccess_8.4.0_x86.msi"* from the official download site and get a warning during setup, that there are components missing with a download link where I can find *"accessruntime_4288-1001_x86_en-us.exe"* (same with x64).

I tried first the x86, but it fails, because there is a 64bit "Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration" on my system. And trying to install the x64 fails too, because there is a 32bit "Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component" on my system.

I can run SSMA without any problems, load the *.accdb*, connect to SQL-Server, but it fails to read the accdb's meta data:

> Access Object Collector error: Database
>        Die COM-Klassenfactory für die Komponente mit CLSID {CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419} konnte aufgrund des folgenden
>   Fehlers nicht abgerufen werden: 80040154 Klasse nicht registriert
>   (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Please make
>   sure that you are using the correct version of SQL Server Migration
>   Assistant. If you have 32-bit Microsoft Access installed, then you
>   will need to use 32-bit version of the Migration Assistant. In order
>   to use 64-bit version of Migration Assistant, you will need to install
>   64-bit Microsoft Access components available at
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=834402.
>        An error occurred while loading database information.

The german part translates to: *The COM-class could not be executed due to the given error (class not registered)*.

A search for the given CLSID brings me back to the access runtime components.

Question:

- How can I use SSMA, if I cannot install the needed runtime?
- Or: How can I install missing components, if the installation routine does not work (e.g. shift the DLL to GAC with gacutil manually)

### EDIT:

In the meanwhile I tried to use SSMA x64 to no avail...

### UPDATE

In the meanwhile I found [this (german) instruction](https://www.ugg.li/setup-fehler-office-16-click-to-run-extensibility-component-64-bit-registration/) how to find and remove the "Click-to-Run" services.

In short: Go to `%windir%\installer`, make sure that explorer is showing you the column "Betreff" (I don't know, how this is called in English, might be "regarding"). You can find the MSI-packages. Copy them somewhere and perform a right-click. Now you can choose "uninstall".

After removing these "click-to-run" stuff from my notebook I can proceed but run into the next error:

> [...] because you have these Click-to-run installer based Office
>   programs installed on your computer 1) Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus -
>   en-us and 2) Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - de-de". Windows Installer
>   and Click-to-Run editions of Office programs don't get along for this
>   version, so you can only have one type installed at a time. [...]

So my new question is:

Can we use SSMA together with MS-Access 365 and - if not - is there an alternative?

Well, I might set up a pc just for this *one-time-issue*...

Thank you for any hint...

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Yes, probably... But I don't want to remove Office from a company's PC. I think I'll rather setup a VM for this...

Comment: @ComputerVersteher It's a pre-installed company's laptop... I won't fiddle around with that. However, Office seems to be just one 32 bit O365 (on a 64 bit Win 10). Thank you anyway...

Comment: Error Message indicates that you are running`SSMAforAccess.exe`but you have to run the x86 version`SSMAforAccess32.exe`(same path) on x86 Office. Same with ODBC-Administrator (search for ODBC, then start ODBC x86)(`%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcas32.exe`). Maybe you have to install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)